# Rails endpoint for ajax request using json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I want to build a endpoint that will accept an ajax request, update a record associated with that request, then create a new object based on the updated record and send it back to the client to be used.

```
def tested
     @prime = PrimeNumber.where(testNumber: id).first
     @prime.update_attributes(prime_params) 

     next = PrimeNumber.where(wasTested: false).first
    if next != nil
        @toTest = needWork


    else
        lastNum =  PrimeNumber.last.testNumber
        nextNum = lastNum + 1
        newNum = PrimeNumber.new
        newNum.testNumber = nextNum
        newNum.wasTested = false 
        newNum.isPrime = false
        newNum.save
        @toTest = PrimeNumber.last
    end
end

 private 
    def prime_params 
        params.require(:prime_number).permit(:testNumber, :isPrime, :wasTested, :id) 
    end
```

everything worked when I was just using post and then reloading the view however i do not need to render any views or partial views. Ideally I would like to be able to send information back and forth in the background of my web app without it making any visible changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily adapt your current method `tested` to return a JSON response if there is an AJAX request.

Just add something like this to the end of your code:

```
def tested
    // ...
    if request.xhr?
        render :json => @prime
    end
end
```

`@prime` would be returned as JSON.

And then in your view, change it so the request is done by AJAX (perhaps by setting `remote: true` on the form helper, depends on how you do things).

See this guide for details: [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'remote: true' in your form_for tag, which makes it ajax request.

and In response you can create tested.js.erb file in your views.

In tested.js.erb you have @prime accessible and you can use it anywhere, append that in the table without reloading the page.

This link is going to be helpful for you.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html